# Make bar plot bars to extend from maximum value to mean rather than from 0 to mean

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tidyverse

In my bar plot I have reversed the y-axis so that lower values are at the top, but I'd like the bars to extend up from the x-axis.

Is there a way to change the direction from which bars extend?

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mean_mpg)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 35))
```

The code above creates the bar plot with the bars extending from the top of the plot, which I do not want.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the result to be? For example, would you want the bar for 6-cyl to extend from 26.6 at the bottom, upwards to 6.9, leaving a gap between 6.9 and 0? My first impression is that it would not make any sense quantitatively.

Comment: So you want the numbers on the y-axis to be reversed but not the bars?

Comment: I'd like the bar to extend from 35 at the x-axis up to 26.7, 19.7, and 15.1.  I'm just using mtcars as a reprex. It makes more sense in the real context where I am showing people's ratings of a program where 1 is best and 5 is worst.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
# some data
set.seed(123)
d <- cbind.data.frame(a=1:5, b=sample(1:5, replace = T))
d
  a b
1 1 5
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 3
5 5 1
# the plot
d %>% 
  mutate(b2=5-b) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(a,b2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylim(0,5)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:5, labels = as.character(5:0))
```

[image]